# Bootstrap - Mesclar linhas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como faço para Melclar duas ou mais celulas no Bootstrap?

Vou postar o codigo:

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span4">4</div>
         <div class="span8">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span4">4</div>
         <div class="span8">8</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**OBS**: Basicamente é mesclar a célula 4 das duas linhas em uma só.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não tem como quebrar um elemento row (inclusive, é o que garante a estabilidade do visual do Bootstrap!).

No Bootstrap as divs ficam empilhadas por padrão, então você pode se aproveitar disso. Mude seu código para:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span4">               
         </div>
         <div class="span8">
           <div>A</div>
           <div>B</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Ao seja, ao invés de dobrar o tamanho do span4, dividimos o span8 em dois.

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan